# How can I define constructor when the class member parameters have the same name?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, member-functions, function-parameter

```
class MyStrValArray
{
private:
   vector<char> p;
public:
   MyStrValArray(const int n = 10, const int i = 1, const char ch = 'a')
   {}
   ~MyStrValArray();
   void init(const int n);
   void clear();
   unsigned capacity();
   unsigned size();
   char get(const int i);
   void set(const char ch, const int i);
   void remove(const unsigned int i);
   void pushData(const char ch);
   char showData();
};
```

This is the class I wrote.
Some of the class member functions have the same parameter name, for example, `ch`, `i`. 
In this case, how can I define a constructor when the class member parameters have the same name?

+) I wanted to check whether the constructor well defined, so in the main function, I wrote `p2.init()`, without any parameter.
Like this:

```
    MyStrValArray p2;
    p2.init();
```

`init` function looks like this:

```
void MyStrValArray::init(const int n) //Done
{
   p.reserve(n);
   cout << "a vector with size " << n << " created" << endl;
}
```

and I got this message:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'MyStrValArray::init()'|
```

I also wrote:

```
p2.get();
p2.set();

char MyStrValArray::get(const int i)
{
   return p.at(i);
}

void MyStrValArray::set(const char ch, const int i)
{
   p[i] = ch;
   cout << "p[" << i << "]" << "changed to " << ch << endl;
}
```

And `p2.get()`, `p2.set()` also have the same error.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Names of function parameters don't conflict across functions, so you're fine.

Comment: I wanted to check whether the constructor well defined, so in the main function I wrote p2.init(), without any parameter, and I got this message: "error: no matching function for call to 'MyStrValArray::get()'|".

Comment: Then add that information to the question. (as code, not a text description). Also, make an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't reproduce your error with the provided code.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be calling `get` anywhere, Which line of code does the error come from?

Comment: I edited the post just now, please check!

Comment: You need to pass arguments to `get`, etc, or declare them with default arguments. See the below answer.

Comment: You seem to have fundamental missunderstanding of function declarations in C++. Parameter names are _not_ part of a functions signature, nor do they work like global variables or something. In a declaration those names have only semantic meaning; `MyStrValArray(const int = 10, const int = 1, const char = 'a')` would be a perfectly fine declaration.

Answer (score 4):

You declared and defined the `init` function with an `int`eger argument

```
class MyStrValArray
{
 public:
       void init(const int n);
       // ...
}

void MyStrValArray::init(const int n)
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ --> argument n
{
   // ...code
}
```

that means the calling the function will only work with passing with an argument. You should be doing

```
 MyStrValArray p2;
 p2.init(3); // pass the `n`
```

---

If you intend to call without any arguments, you should provide a [default argument to it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments)

```
class MyStrValArray
{
 public:           
      void (const int n = 3); // declaration: provide the default argument
      //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      // ...
}

void MyStrValArray::init(const int n) // definition
{
    // ...code
}
```

Now you could

```
 MyStrValArray p2;
 p2.init(); // the n = 3
```

---

> "`error: no matching function for call to 'MyStrValArray::get()'|`".
>   What could be the problem?

The above mentioned is applied for the case of `MyStrValArray::get()` function too. Hence the error. Choose one of the mentioned ways to get around the problem.